# PhpPgAdmin Syntax error when creating View

Tags: sql, postgresql, view, phppgadmin, updatable-views

I am attempting to create a View in PhpPgAdmin (PostGreSQL db) which has the following SQL statement:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myTable.error IS NULL;
```

PhpPgAdmin gives me the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "DELETE" at character 59
>   In statement:
>   CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW "Schema1"."Delete empty errors" AS DELETE FROM myTable WHERE myTable.error IS NULL;

As far as I can tell this SQL statement is valid, and I have delete privileges for the table.  Is the DELETE statement not allowed in Views?  Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views are used to display the data from SELECT statements only (usually when the SELECT is complex).  Views cannot contain DELETES, UPDATES, or INSERTS.

Perhaps you want a [function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)?

EDIT:  As OMG Ponies points out, you can have updateable views, but thats where you would issue a DELETE to an existing view and then use a RULE to rewrite the query as a DELETE.

And please, please don't wrap a function call to do a DELETE as a side effect in a view.  Its unexpected and Jesus shoots a puppy every time this happens.

Comment: Postgres does support updatable views via rules: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createview.html

Comment: And a function call can be wrapped inside a view.

Comment: OK, you can have updatable views using rules, and can wrap a function call inside a view, but I've never seen a plain DELETE inside a view

Comment: While, yes, you can have updateable views, it didn't really appear to be what was required.  He wasn't trying to DELETE from a view, he was trying to create a view that is a delete....which is different.

Comment: Actually you are correct, I need to use a function.  I'm just trying to execute a one time task to clean up a large dataset.  So I took your advice and created a Function, but there doesn't seem to be a way to execute the function from within PhpPgAdmin.  What is recommended for this sort of thing?

Comment: select call_your_function_here();